# Digital Ocean CentOS7 server, unable to --skip-grant-tables or restart mysql

Tags: centos, mysql, centos7, mariadb

I set up a Digital Ocean droplet (server) a few days ago and need to access mysql.  No password for root is working amongst what I've tried.  However this command:

```
service mysql[d] stop
```

Doesn't work.  Apparently I am supposed to issue this command:

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb.service
```

But that results in

```
Failed to stop mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not loaded.
```

Furthermore, this command

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking & mysql -u root
```

Results in these responses:

```
sudo: mysqld_safe: command not found
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1   sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

I am logged into the server as root; what do I do from here?

Comment: First you need to remember whether you installed MySQL, or MariaDB, or as seems likely, neither.

Comment: What is the output from these command? 'rpm -qa | grep mariadb' and 'rpm -qa | grep mysqld' and 'rpm -qa | grep mysql'

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyFornito, the output from the mariadb was `mariadb-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64
mariadb-libs-5.5.50-1.el7_2.x86_64` and the output from mysql was `php-mysql-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64` - mysqld returned nothing.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - it appears I have BOTH on my server.

Comment: Really? I only see MariaDB there.

Comment: Um.. you are right Michael - that's php-mysql so that's not it.  So, I only have mariadb, what next?  Trying to restart it does nothing, and `mysqld_safe` doesn't exist/isn't installed on the server.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
yum remove mysql
```

Then try

```
service mariadb restart
```

Then look at the out from

```
service mariadb status
```

You should see it running then the commands your tried early should work

if

```
 yum remove mysql
```

does not work Try

```
 chkconfig mysql off
```

Reboot and try to start maria again.

Comment: No success with the first part.  I got: [root@centos-8gb-nyc2-01 ~]# service mariadb restart --
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  mariadb.service -- 
Failed to restart mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[root@centos-8gb-nyc2-01 ~]# service mariadb status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mariadb.service
● mariadb.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: `ckconfig` only results in a -bash: command not found error.

Comment: chkconfig <-- forgot the h

Comment: After reboot try yum install mariadb

Comment: chkconfig only works on sysv services You need to use `systemctl enable`.